# Enable highlighting of MenuItem outside of ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem, contentpresenter

I've been at it for a while and it's driving me crazy. Here's my problem... I have a `Menu` and it uses the default template in which I've altered colors upon highlighting, default state, etc.  So, there's no point posting it here -- it's virtually exact same thing  (and it's a lot of template code).

What my problem is the spacing between the `MenuItems` created by the template's `Margin`property.  It is template-binded with the padding property and produces a `(2, 3, 2, 3)` margin all around the `ContentPresenter` of the template.

I want to keep that property and need it to separate the items; however, mousing over only activates highlighted state when the mouse is over the `ContentPresenter` and nothing else.  So, the "button" feel won't actuate until I mouse over the words themselves.  `ContentPresenter` does not have padding, so I'm not sure how to deal with it.  I tried editing the triggers that came with the template to work on other parts, but it doesn't work (they don't fire off).

The triggers that come with the template only work with the `ContentPresenter`.  I tried wrapping it in `ContentControl` to see if I can gain `Padding`, but the binding for `Padding` doesn't work, only for margin... not sure why (it shows up in the Properties, but the addition of padding is not visible):

```
<ContentControl SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
</ContentControl>
```

I also tried replacing `ContentPresenter` with `ContentControl` altogether, but once again suffered from Padding not binding properly and manual Padding didn't do anything either.  Something is overwriting it, perhaps.

Any idea how I can actuate triggers in the empty space between those `MenuItems`?  The way I've been dealing with it is by adding whitespace into my `MenuItem` headers... and that's just absurd.

Here's my template:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemSelectionFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">M 0,5.1 L 1.7,5.2 L 3.4,7.1 L 8,0.4 L 9.2,0 L 3.3,10.8 Z</Geometry>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#FFEFF6FB" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="1,12" ContentSource="Icon" Height="0"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Width="Auto" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="1" Height="Auto" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FFEFF6FB" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFEFF6FB">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Width="9" Height="11" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="#0C12A1" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}"/>
            </Border>-->
            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--<Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>-->
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>-->
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFC0E5FF"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>-->
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemPressedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#28717070" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#50717070" Offset="0.75"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#90717070" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubMenuBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFEFF6FB"/>

<Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>

<Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <DockPanel Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="R1" Width="1" Fill="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="B1" Height="1" Fill="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="L1" Width="1" Fill="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="T1" Height="1" Fill="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentContainer" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="R1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="B1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="L1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="T1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentContainer" Value="3,3,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>

<Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>

<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="false" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="0">
                        <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="0">
                                <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </RepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}" Grid.Row="2" Focusable="false" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="0">
                        <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="100">
                                <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"/>
        <DockPanel>
            <!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,1"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="0">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" Background="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>-->
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#90717070"/>-->
            <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>-->
            <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>-->
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>-->
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>-->
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>-->
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"/>
        <DockPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>-->
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Path Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="#FFEFF6FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Without knowing what you do in your custom template, anything would just by blind guessing in the dark. Note that in the default ControlTemplate for MenuItem, MenuItem.Padding is bound to ContentPresenter.Margin property -- and mousing over/into the margin of that ContentPresenter still highlights the menu item. Although you say your template is virtually the same as the default template, it behaves differently -- which makes me think you altered it substantially at places related to its behaviour...

Comment: @elgonzo I'll post the template.

Comment: Could you please just post the template part relevant to the MenuItem, especially those parts you have altered (no matter whether you think they are related to the behaviour or not).

Comment: @elgonzo I posted all I had and at this point I don't know which parts would not be relevant.

Comment: Oh... that's quite a mountain of text then o_O

Comment: Some questions to sort things out: Does the mouse-over issue only affect MenuItems in the menubar, or also/instead of in pulldown menus? How about MenuItems in popup/context menus?

Comment: @elgonzo It appears to be only the initial MenuItems.  Everything within popup menus appears to be functioning properly.  I am able to move my mouse into any portion and highlighting occurs immediately.  Maybe I deleted something important accidentally?

Comment: Okay, then only TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey and TopLevelItemTemplateKey are of concern...

Comment: Ah, i see you have two Rectangles defined in the Grid for TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey (which is used for menu items in the menubar which have pull-down menus).

Comment: Right, those are default.

Comment: Okay, TopLevelItemTemplateKey is affected. The question is why... Could you please just reduce the template in the question to the one for TopLevelItemTemplateKey? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, i think i know what it is (still would need testing). Note that you have in that particular template a menu item whose background is not set (=null). Setting the background explicitly to "Transparent" should help, i hope.

Comment: Yupp, it does. Answer follows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the MenuItem template with the ResourceID `TopLevelItemTemplateKey`.

Note that in this template no background is set for the transparent areas of the menu item. Technically speaking, the background in these areas is not transparent, it is `null` - not setting a background will for many UI elements let the mouse hit test fail  in regions without content (hit-testing is not done pixel-by-pixel but rather by specific `UIElement.InputHitTest` method implementations).

Setting the background explicitly to `"Transparent"` on the outermost UI element in your template will fix this issue:

```
<ControlTemplate
    x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey,
           TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}"
    TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"
>

    <!-- ### FIX: SETTING THE GRID BACKGROUND TO "TRANSPARENT" ### -->

    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"/>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(If you want to know more about hit testing in WPF, [read here in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).)

Comment: I also had to do it on `TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey`, but you got it! :D  Works like a charm and I very much appreciate your hard work.  I will definitely check out that link.

Comment: Okay, i did not look any further at TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey as soon as i realized that you did not bound the Padding there ;) Anyway, i am glad i could help.

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple. I was trying to figure it out for three days now.  Learned something new... hit tests... heh. :)